# Are indexes from composite keys enough?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, indexing, composite-key

This is how my table looks:

```
CREATE TABLE pics(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT,
  page INTEGER,
  w INTEGER,
  h INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(page) REFERENCES pages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  UNIQUE(name, page)
);

CREATE INDEX "myidx" ON "pics"("page");  # is this needed?
```

so `UNIQUE(name, page)` should create an index. But is this index enough to make fast queries that involve the `page` field only? Like selecting a set of "pics" `WHERE page = ?`. or `JOIN pages.id ON pics.page` ? Or should I create another index (myidx) just for the page field?

Comment: In any composite index, it *might* be used if your query uses the n **leftmost columns** (where n is between 1 and the number of columns in your index). In your case, if your query uses `name` or  `name` and `page` it might be used - if your query is on `page` only, that composite index is definitely useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a composite index as a phone book.  The phone book is *sorted* by last name, then the first name.  If you're given the name *Bob Smith*, you can quickly find the *S* section, then *Sm*, then all the *Smith*'s, then eventually *Bob*.  This is fast because you have both keys in the index.  Since the book is organized by last name first, it would also be just as trivial to find *all* the *Smith* entries.

Now imagine trying to find *all* the people named *Bob* in the entire phone book.  Much harder, right?

This is analogous to how the index on disk is organized as well.  Finding all the rows with a certain *page* column when the list of sorted in `(name, page)` order will basically result in a sequential scan of all the rows, looking one by one for anything that has that *page*.

For more information on how indexes work, I recommend reading through [Use the Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Answer (score 6):

As stated, you will need your other `myidx` index, because your `UNIQUE` index specifies `name` first. In other words, it can be used to query by:

1. `name`
2. `name` and `page`
3. But *not* by `page` alone.

Your other option is to reorder the `UNIQUE` index and place the `page` column first. Then it can be used for `page` only queries, but will become incompatible with `name` only queries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to analyse the query(s) that will use this table and determine what fields the query will use to sort the results. You should index the fields that are used for sorting the most.

Comment: For sorting I may use `w` and `h` which don't have indexes :/ If what you are saying is correct, I'd have to add indexes for all fields on my table..

Comment: Mike Christensen is saying what I wanted to say.